# I can't create a DataBase on Apache NetBeans 12.3

Tags: database

[Java DB Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXCMb.png)

In each time I try to create a DataBase I got this message, Knowing that I'm using Apache NetBeans 12.3

Comment: Well, did you download Derby and register the driver?

Comment: No, I didn't. How can I do that?